# Let $A$ be the set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$. Show that $P(A)=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A$ be the set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$. Show that $P(A)=1$ , where $P$ is Lebesgue measure.

---

What ever we do there are infinite irrational numbers for every two rational numbers, right?
and we know that single point probability is zero.

it's obvious but i need more mathematical answer. Thank you.

Comment: You know $P([0,1])$, and you know $P([0,1] \cap \Bbb Q)$...

Comment: There are countably many rationals, so countably many in our interval. Now use countable additivity.

Comment: There are also infinitely many rational numbers between every two irrational numbers, so your argument doesn't work.

Comment: @TonyK, I think Andre and Mike point towards $$P(A)=P[0,1]-P([0,1]\cap\Bbb Q)$$ using addivitity of Lebesgue measure. But there's a countable set there which is then of measure zero, so...

Comment: @Timbuc: I was addressing the OP.

Comment: Ah. It's tough to tell when names aren't written, @TonyK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\Bbb Q = \bigcup_{q\in\Bbb Q} \{q\}
$$

and $P(\bigcup A_n)\le \sum P(A_n)$ if $(A_n)$ is enumerable.

Comment: thank you but can you be more specific?

Comment: @usengec I added another hint.